# How to control public resoucre(js, css, image,...) in Codeigniter like Express

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter, express

I'm newbie in `Codeigniter`. Almost the whole time ago I use `NodeJS`. Can you show me how to control public resource in `Codeigniter` like `Express`? I want use `/js/dev` in development mode instead of `/js`.

example:

When first load web page with path: `http://xxxx.com/js/default.js` will get content from `/js/dev/default.js` instead of `/js/default.js` at `development mode`

Below is my code in Express for this idea.

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {//path dev -> min to product
  app.use('/js', express.static('client/js/dev'))
  app.use('/css', express.static('client/css/dev'))
}
```

Comment: You can create a directory in the root directory to keep your static files there.

Answer (score 1):

You can create any folder on your root directory. After that you can access those files with base_url(), be sure your base_url is correct, you can change it on **'application/config/config.php'**

```
<?php
echo base_url('public/js/xyz.js');
echo base_url('uploads/img/15.jpg');
```